# Mahout - Simple classification issue

Tags: java, classification, mahout

I am trying to build a simple model that can **classify points into 2 partitions** of the 2D space:

1. I **train the model** by specifying few **points and the partition they belong to**.
2. I use the model to **predict the group (classify)** in which the **test point may fall**.

Unfortunately, I am not getting the answer as expected. Am I missing something in my code or am I doing something wrong?

```
public class SimpleClassifier {

    public static class Point{
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public Point(int x,int y){
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
            Point p = (Point)  arg0;
            return( (this.x == p.x) &&(this.y== p.y));
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return  this.x + " , " + this.y ; 
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Point,Integer> points = new HashMap<SimpleClassifier.Point, Integer>();

        points.put(new Point(0,0), 0);
        points.put(new Point(1,1), 0);
        points.put(new Point(1,0), 0);
        points.put(new Point(0,1), 0);
        points.put(new Point(2,2), 0);


        points.put(new Point(8,8), 1);
        points.put(new Point(8,9), 1);
        points.put(new Point(9,8), 1);
        points.put(new Point(9,9), 1);


        OnlineLogisticRegression learningAlgo = new OnlineLogisticRegression();
        learningAlgo =  new OnlineLogisticRegression(2, 2, new L1());
        learningAlgo.learningRate(50);

        //learningAlgo.alpha(1).stepOffset(1000);

        System.out.println("training model  \n" );
        for(Point point : points.keySet()){
            Vector v = getVector(point);
            System.out.println(point  + " belongs to " + points.get(point));
            learningAlgo.train(points.get(point), v);
        }

        learningAlgo.close();


        //now classify real data
        Vector v = new RandomAccessSparseVector(2);
        v.set(0, 0.5);
        v.set(1, 0.5);

        Vector r = learningAlgo.classifyFull(v);
        System.out.println(r);

        System.out.println("ans = " );
        System.out.println("no of categories = " + learningAlgo.numCategories());
        System.out.println("no of features = " + learningAlgo.numFeatures());
        System.out.println("Probability of cluster 0 = " + r.get(0));
        System.out.println("Probability of cluster 1 = " + r.get(1));

    }

    public static Vector getVector(Point point){
        Vector v = new DenseVector(2);
        v.set(0, point.x);
        v.set(1, point.y);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ans = 
no of categories = 2
no of features = 2
Probability of cluster 0 = 3.9580985042775296E-4
Probability of cluster 1 = 0.9996041901495722
```

99 % of times the output show more probability for `cluster 1`. **Why?**

Comment: @sean-owen can u please help me with this?

Comment: please post expected output

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you didn't include bias(intercept) term, which is always 1.
You need to add bias term(1) to your point class.

This is a very basic mistake many experienced people in machine learning commit. It might be a good idea to invest some time in learning theory. [Andrew Ng's lectures](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes4.pdf) are one great place to learn.

To get your code give expected output, the following things need to be changed.

1. Bias term added.
2. Learning parameter was too high. Changed it to 10

Now you'll getting P(0)=0.9999 for class 0.

Here's a complete working example that gives correct results:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.L1;
import org.apache.mahout.classifier.sgd.OnlineLogisticRegression;
import org.apache.mahout.math.DenseVector;
import org.apache.mahout.math.RandomAccessSparseVector;
import org.apache.mahout.math.Vector;


class Point{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Point(int x,int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
        Point p = (Point)  arg0;
        return( (this.x == p.x) &&(this.y== p.y));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  this.x + " , " + this.y ; 
    }
}

public class SimpleClassifier {



    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Map<Point,Integer> points = new HashMap<Point, Integer>();

            points.put(new Point(0,0), 0);
            points.put(new Point(1,1), 0);
            points.put(new Point(1,0), 0);
            points.put(new Point(0,1), 0);
            points.put(new Point(2,2), 0);

            points.put(new Point(8,8), 1);
            points.put(new Point(8,9), 1);
            points.put(new Point(9,8), 1);
            points.put(new Point(9,9), 1);


            OnlineLogisticRegression learningAlgo = new OnlineLogisticRegression();
            learningAlgo =  new OnlineLogisticRegression(2, 3, new L1());
            learningAlgo.lambda(0.1);
            learningAlgo.learningRate(10);

            System.out.println("training model  \n" );

            for(Point point : points.keySet()){

                Vector v = getVector(point);
                System.out.println(point  + " belongs to " + points.get(point));
                learningAlgo.train(points.get(point), v);
            }

            learningAlgo.close();

            Vector v = new RandomAccessSparseVector(3);
            v.set(0, 0.5);
            v.set(1, 0.5);
            v.set(2, 1);

            Vector r = learningAlgo.classifyFull(v);
            System.out.println(r);

            System.out.println("ans = " );
            System.out.println("no of categories = " + learningAlgo.numCategories());
            System.out.println("no of features = " + learningAlgo.numFeatures());
            System.out.println("Probability of cluster 0 = " + r.get(0));
            System.out.println("Probability of cluster 1 = " + r.get(1));

    }

    public static Vector getVector(Point point){
        Vector v = new DenseVector(3);
        v.set(0, point.x);
        v.set(1, point.y);
        v.set(2, 1);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2 , 2 belongs to 0
1 , 0 belongs to 0
9 , 8 belongs to 1
8 , 8 belongs to 1
0 , 1 belongs to 0
0 , 0 belongs to 0
1 , 1 belongs to 0
9 , 9 belongs to 1
8 , 9 belongs to 1
{0:2.470723149516907E-6,1:0.9999975292768505}
ans = 
no of categories = 2
no of features = 3
Probability of cluster 0 = 2.470723149516907E-6
Probability of cluster 1 = 0.9999975292768505
```

*Note that I defined the class Point outside the SimpleClassifier class, but that's only to make the code more readable and is not essential.*

See what happens when you change learning rate. Read notes on cross-validation for understanding how to select learning rate.

```
Learning Rate => Probability of cluster 0
0.001 => 0.4991116089
0.01 => 0.492481585
0.1 => 0.469961472
1 => 0.5327745322
10 => 0.9745740393
100 => 0
1000 => 0
```

**Selecting learning rate:**

1. It is common to run stochastic gradient descent as we have done by starting with a fixed learning rate α, by slowly letting the learning rate α decrease to zero as
   the algorithm runs, it is also possible to ensure that the parameters will converge to the
   global minimum rather then merely oscillate around the minimum.
2. As in this case, when we use a constant α, you can make an initial selection, running gradient descent and observing the cost function, and adjusting the learning rate accordingly. It is explained [here](http://openclassroom.stanford.edu/MainFolder/DocumentPage.php?course=MachineLearning&doc=exercises/ex3/ex3.html)

Comment: could you share the link to notes on cross-validation, which you mentioned explain how to select training rate?

Comment: Hi @mucaho, I've edited my answer to add that. For other notes on ML, I would recommend http://cs229.stanford.edu/materials.html

Comment: You say that `P(0)=0.9999 for class 0`, but your console output shows that `Probability of cluster 0 = 2.470723149516907E-6` and `Probability of cluster 1 = 0.9999975292768505`. I verified the output, it's the same on my machine. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it the potential **issues** with your classification example:

- Use the default values for the `OnlineLogisticRegression` training (`learningRate`, etc...)
- Introduce constant bias (it's just another predictor variable that has the constant value `1`)
- Shuffle the training data (don't provide the training data corresponding to the 1st cluster first and then the the data providing to the 2nd cluster afterwards)
- Increase the amount of training data significantly

For further details on this potential issues, refer to the book [Mahout in Action](http://www.manning.com/owen/).

**Results** after "fixing" the potential issues:
The test point `<0.5, 0.5>` is classified to the `cluster 0` with a probability of ca. `0.89` consistently across multiple runs.
That sounds like a reasonable output, as the other points near the origin (that were used for training the model) also belong to `cluster 0`.

**Code**

```
public class SimpleClassifier {

    public static class Point {
        public int x;
        public int y;

        public Point(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object arg0) {
            Point p = (Point) arg0;
            return ((this.x == p.x) && (this.y == p.y));
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return this.x + " , " + this.y;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Point, Integer> points = new HashMap<Point, Integer>();

        points.put(new Point(0, 0), 0);
        points.put(new Point(1, 1), 0);
        points.put(new Point(1, 0), 0);
        points.put(new Point(0, 1), 0);
        points.put(new Point(2, 2), 0);


        points.put(new Point(8, 8), 1);
        points.put(new Point(8, 9), 1);
        points.put(new Point(9, 8), 1);
        points.put(new Point(9, 9), 1);


        OnlineLogisticRegression learningAlgo = new OnlineLogisticRegression(2, 3, new L1());

        System.out.println("training model  \n");
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            List<Point> randomPoints = new ArrayList<>(points.keySet());
            Collections.shuffle(randomPoints);
            for (Point point : randomPoints) {
                Vector v = getVector(point);
                System.out.println(point + " belongs to " + points.get(point));
                learningAlgo.train(points.get(point), v);
            }
        }
        learningAlgo.close();


        //now classify real data
        Vector v = new RandomAccessSparseVector(3);
        v.set(0, 0.5);
        v.set(1, 0.5);
        v.set(2, 1);

        Vector r = learningAlgo.classify(v);
        System.out.println(r);

        System.out.println("ans = ");
        System.out.println("no of categories = " + learningAlgo.numCategories());
        System.out.println("no of features = " + learningAlgo.numFeatures());
        System.out.println("Probability of cluster 0 = " + (1.0d - r.get(0)));
        System.out.println("Probability of cluster 1 = " + r.get(0));

    }

    public static Vector getVector(Point point) {
        Vector v = new DenseVector(3);
        v.set(0, point.x);
        v.set(1, point.y);
        v.set(2, 1);

        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor thing - do not edit questions in such a way that it changes the question, ie adding additional explanation. That information can be included in your answer (as you've done here) or in a comment to the question.

Comment: @admdrew Ok, I thought the additional explanation was part of the question (e.g. the user mentioned that the console output was wrong, but he did not mention what he expected to see - I just extracted his expectation from the source code, so others would not need to browse source code to see his expected console output)